# Pseudoelement RGBA arrow color doesn't match parent

Tags: css, pseudo-element

I'm creating a pseudoelement arrow under a `div` (`#telegram-join`), both of which have background/border colors as RGBA values (`rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25)`), but the arrow is being affected differently and appears darker than the `div`. Is this because it's smaller? How can I match them? Thanks!

HTML

```
<div id="telegram-join" class="bg-combo">
  <h1><i class="fa fa-telegram"></i> Chat with us on Telegram</h1>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.bg-combo {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-radius: 8px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  width: fit-content;
  background-color: white;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25);
  text-align: center;
}

.bg-combo h1 {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 2em;
  line-height: 1.5;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.bg-combo h1 i {
  margin-right: 10px;
}

#telegram-join {
  position: relative;
  margin: 15px auto 25px;
}

#telegram-join :after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  margin-left: -15px;
  margin-top: -15px;
  border: 15px solid #fff;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-color: transparent transparent rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25) rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25);
  content: '';
}
```

Demo: [CodePen](https://codepen.io/ourcore/pen/prYMQY)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your background-color (of the container) has 0.25% opacity, and the pseudo-element (which is inside that element) also has 0.25% opacity (so it's background is no longer the body-background, it's the new background of the container element - which has the opacity).

You can solve this by setting the opacity of the pseudo-element to 0.125%:

```
border-color: transparent transparent rgba(255,255,255,0.125) rgba(255,255,255,0.125);
```

Or set the background on both elements to the actual color you want:

```
border-color: transparent transparent #D7D7D7 #D7D7D7;
```

Here is the update to your codepen:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/eEXqaO

Comment: Gotcha. I had a feeling it could've been a hierarchical issue. I didn't use hex values for easier opacity control. Thanks!